# In Ancient Greek, why ἑπτά vs. ἕβδομος?

Tags: greek, morphology

I was marveling today at the word [hebdomadal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hebdomadal), from the Greek ἑπτά for seven. But that had me wondering why words derived from seven sometimes use /bd/ and other times /pt/. I notice, for instance, that the word for seventh is ἕβδομος. (The same could be asked of ὀκτώ and ὄγδοος.) And among compound numerals, the cardinals persist in using /pt/ and /kt/, while the ordinals persist in using /bd/ and /gd/. What's going on here?

I consulted Smyth's *Greek Grammar*, and it distinguishes in §16 between the *order* of stops—/p/ and /t/, as unvoiced stops, belong to the first order, while /b/ and /d/, as voiced stops, belong to the second—and per §82, a labial or palatal before a dental changes to the dental's order. Smyth lists ἑπτά as an example in §82.c. N. 1, so I think I'm on the right track. It appears the dental is changing from smooth to middle order, and the labial with it—my question is, why?

Comment: Good question. I really don't know under which circumstances a stop would change from voiced (dgb) to unvoiced (tkp) or the converse. They do that when followed by another stop, as in the the p and the b in this case; but why would the t and the d be different, as they must come from the same root? When did they differentiate, and by what rule can this be explained?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Greek word for seven, hepta, like Sanskrit sapta, Latin septem, and others, points to an Indo-European *septm. In Greek *s becomes h, and the syllabic *m becomes a. In the word for “seventh”, IE *septm-o-, the m is a consonant (non-syllabic) and remains m in Greek, giving *heptmos, and then (with voicing of pt to bd before the voiced m) *hebdmos, and then (with insertion of a vowel to break up the cluster) hebdomos.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have to ask, what's happening with ὀκτώ and ὄγδοος, then? Is it something different? I see [the PIE was](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/o%E1%B8%B1t%E1%B9%93w) *oḱtṓw or *h₁oḱtṓw—the long o didn't drop out, and no stop follows it, anyway. Analogy, maybe?

Comment: @Nick. “Analogy” is the easy way out, but as yet no one has suggested anything better.

Comment: The explanation I've heard for ὄγδοος is *oktwos > *ogdwos > ogdowos, exactly parallel to ἕβδομος, with voicing assimilation to w. I don't know enough about the morphology of PIE ordinals to say whether the absence of ō is expected.

Comment: @TKR. Yes, this and other proposals are discussed by Beekes, s.v.  ὄγδοος. In this case it is the assumed suffix *wo that is problematic.

Comment: More precisely, that proposal doesn't necessarily assume a suffix *wo, but a -w as part of the stem. But it all seems very unclear.